# Two questions regarding excel macros

Tags: excel, vba

First question: I want to run a macro automatically when a specific cell value changes, however when the cell value changes, it doesn't run. The only way it runs is when I go to the "Macros" section under the developer tab and manually run the macro.

Second Question: I have a cell that is formatted as text and displays "somenumber% / someothernumber%" and I want the negative values to be colored red and the positive values to colored green. The problem is it only registers the first value, so if it's positive then all of the cell values are green, and vice versa for negative. Here is the specific text formatting: `= TEXT(AS4,"[>0]+#,###0.000%;[<0]-#,###0.000%")&" "&"/"&" "&TEXT(AS6,"[>0]+#,###0.000%;[<0]-#,###0.000%")`.

Here is my attempt at both solutions:

```
Sub TextColorChange()

Dim xWs As Worksheet
Set xWs = Sheets("Trading Statistics")

For Row = 10 To 13

    vall = xWs.Cells(Row, 51).Value

        CheckPlus = InStr(1, vall, "+")
        CheckMinus = InStr(1, vall, "-")
        CheckDash = InStr(1, vall, "/")
        part = Len(vall) - CheckDash + 1

        If CheckMinus <> 0 Then
            xWs.Cells(Row, 51).Characters(Start:=CheckMinus, Length:=part).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        End If

        If CheckPlus <> 0 Then
            xWs.Cells(Row, 51).Characters(Start:=CheckPlus, Length:=part).Font.ColorIndex = 10
        End If

Next Row

End Sub
--------------------------------    
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim Xrg As Range
    Set Xrg = Me.Range("AY6")
    If Not Intersect(Xrg, Me.Range("AY6")) Is Nothing Then
       Call TextColorChange
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: And the worksheet change code is in the "Trading Statistics" sheet code module? Note that you can use `Me` to refer to the parent worksheet, which should simplify...

Comment: @BigBen I tried putting the worksheet change code into a module but I got the same results, but for reference should this part of the code be in a module and the macro I'm calling be in the "worksheet" code?

Comment: Worksheet event code goes in the sheet code module. Also, based on the previous comment, you can use `If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("AY6")) Is Nothing Then`. Also, can you elaborate on how the value changes? Manually, via another macro, or is it a formula that changes upon calculation?

Comment: @BigBen Changed it. And to answer your question it's a formula.

Comment: You need the [Worksheet Calculate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)) event then.

Comment: Arghh...updated the code in the question. Still not doing what I want. I used both Me.Range() and the long way I had in the previous version using `Sheets`

Comment: Pretty sure you can't color part of a cell whose value comes from a formula.  Or where the text results in part from a format.

Comment: You'd have to copy the value from this cell and place it an an adjacent cell, and then color-format the copy.

Comment: @TimWilliams yeah unfortunately this was the second option, and I wanted to avoid this because I have single values in the same column on different rows which would make it look tacky

Comment: Instead of using an in-cell formula you can use the Calculate event to populate the cells directly.  Then you can use the formatting with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have an excel file that does this, the code I use to active my macro when a user paste data in a sheet is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("A2")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
                Call Sorting
                Call Pic
    End If


MsgBox "Data updated"

End Sub
```

Sorting and Pic are the macros being called and the above code has to be put in the actual sheet where the macro should trigger (i.e not in the module)

**EDIT**: this answers your first question. Please mark it as helpful if it was, then post your second question in a new post altogether.

Comment: I think as OP noted in the comments that it's a formula, so `Worksheet_Change` is not the way to go unfortunately.